# ko.toJSON returns a invalid JSON when user types in illegal characters

Tags: knockout.js

In Knockout JS, applying Ko.toJSON gives JSON output that is not escaped, hence i couldn't use  it.

There are form fields and also text area with html binding, So if the user types in illegal characters, Ko.toJSON output are not escaped.

How to escape the output of Ko.toJSON?

Escaped, Valid JSON

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "jw_educname": "B.E",
          "jw_eduiname": "Arunai <span class=\"test\">of Engineering</span>"

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But ko.toJSON just outputs `<span class="test">of Engineering</span>` that makes the JSON invalid and unusable.

Comment: What do you mean with "not escaped"? Could you please edit your question and provide a sample with a simple object which you stringify using ko.toJSON, the output you get and also the output you expected?

Comment: I pasted the valid JSON i was expecting, I couldn't paste invalid JSON here.

Comment: If I use your object from above and use the ko.toJSON method the output I get is absolutely correct. I have added the code into a jsfiddle which you can use to check. You can find it at http://jsfiddle.net/S5L5b/. Could you update that jsfiddle to show your issue?

Comment: Yes, the one i pasted is valid JSON, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to paste invalid JSON here. what i get from from ko.toJSON for property js_eduiname is <span class="test">of Engineering</span>

Comment: If you can't paste it here, could you please edit my jsfiddle so that it gives the invalid json you are referring to? ko.toJSON uses the JSON.stringify method implemented by the browser (or the equivalent in json2 or similar, if you include it, for older browsers) for creating the JSON. That json string should really be valid (and in my attempt it was valid), so please try to reproduce your issue in the jsfiddle linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control how an object is converted to JSON(check this link:
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html)
So you can have something like this:

```
YourObject.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this); //easy way to get a clean copy
    copy.PropertyToEncode = copy.PropertyToEncode.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    return copy; //return the copy to be serialized
};
```

Comment: That's the one i was expecting for.